# Monitor existing pipe in-place

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, python-3.3

I'm running a script within a Python 3.3 runtime. This runtime uses several UNIX pipes (not named pipes) to communicate with its parent process. I would like to intercept and inspect the traffic sent across these pipes without otherwise interfering with them.

My initial thought is to:

1. Find the file descriptor for each pipe.
2. Use `os.dup` to duplicate that file descriptor.
3. Create a new pipe. Hook it up to the new file descriptor, also logging the data that passes through it.
4. Use `os.dup2` to replace the old file descriptor with the new pipe.

Is there an easier way?